# NullPointerException: how do i assign it something so it's not null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, playlist

Ok, so I'm trying to create a playlist class that, in the constructor, creates an array of 50 SongRecords. I first got the NPE with my unedited code, so I tried to change it and explicitly wrote for the constructor to assign a no-info SongRecord() to every element in the playlist. However, NPE appears at the line where I refer to the particular song element to be assigned a songrecord. How do I fix it if I can't assign the element a songrecord?

Below is a portion of my code which, I think, is the relevant info for the error. NPE points to the line "this.amount[i]..."

```
public class Playlist {
   private int currentSongs;
   private SongRecord[] amount;
   public static final int MAX=50;


/*Constructor that defaults current number of songs to 0 and max space to be 50 songs*/

public Playlist(){
    this.currentSongs=0;
    SongRecord[] list=new SongRecord[MAX];
    for (int i=0; i<MAX;i++){
        this.amount[i]=new SongRecord();
    }
}
```

Comment: AHAHAHAHAHA I'm so stupid. Thank you very much everyone. Solved my biggest problem in this homework.

Answer (score 4):

You've created a *different* array (with the variable `list`)  - but then tried to populate `amount`:

```
SongRecord[] list=new SongRecord[MAX];
for (int i=0; i<MAX;i++){
    this.amount[i]=new SongRecord();
}
```

`amount` is still null (the default value for all reference type variables) so you're getting an exception.

I suspect you want:

```
amount = new SongRecord[MAX];
for (int i = 0; i < MAX;i++) {
    amount[i] = new SongRecord();
}
```

Or better yet, change `amount` to a variable of type `List<SongRecord>` and then initialize it as:

```
amount = new ArrayList<SongRecord>(); // Or new ArrayList<> if you're using Java 7
```

In general, collection classes are easier to work with than arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized `amount`

```
amount = new SongRecord[MAX];
```

In your constructor, you initialize another `SongRecord` array for some reason. Instead, initialize yours

```
public Playlist(){
    this.currentSongs=0;
    this.amount = new SongRecord[MAX];
    for (int i=0; i<MAX;i++){
        this.amount[i]=new SongRecord();
    }
}
```

If you don't initialize the array, it will reference `null` by default. You cannot access elements of a `null` reference.

Comment: For stylistic consistency with `this.amount[i] = …`, you might initialize with `this.amount = new SongRecord[MAX];`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Sure, I see no problem with that.